# In Android Retrofit, how do I serialize a List for a GET request query?

Tags: android, serialization, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

What is the cleanest way to serialize a List to a query parameter? Currently, my serialization becomes:

```
...search?items[]=this&items[]=cat&items[]=cookie...
```

What I need is the above, but without the brackets. I figured that Gson may have a way to do this, but I am unsure.

**UPDATE:**
One important thing is that this is a dynamic `List` which needs to be posted, not just individual params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamic list, you will probably will want to use @QueryMap

```
@GET("group/{id}/users")
Call<List<User>> groupList(@Path("id") int groupId, @QueryMap Map<String, String> options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your method in your interface this way:

```
@GET("query")
myMethod(@Query("items") String items)
```

And this is the way you should call it:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Item 1");
list.add("Item 2");
list.add("Item 3");
String items = "";
for (String s : list){
    items += s + ",";
}

api.query(items);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could see this example that is on the official documentation of Retrofit 
http://square.github.io/retrofit/

You must annotated each parameter of your method with the annotation @Query.

```
@GET("group/{id}/users")
Call<List<User>> groupList(@Path("id") int groupId, @Query("sort") String sort);
```

[image]

I hope that it helps you.